# RestKit - using colon in Paginator Path crashes

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am using RKPaginator to fetch objects from following URL:

http://devSite.com/api/products?pid=somePid&fl=p7:9&limit=5&offset=0

I am setting the path as follows :

```
NSString*urlPAth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://devSite.com/api/products?pid=%@&fl=p7:9&limit=:perPage&offset=:offset", pid];
```

But it does give an error and crashes :

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[
>   valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant
>   for the key 9.

I know this is because of the colon, but couldn't fine any solution to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use : in the path when you're using injected parameters because it will be treated as a parameter. If you need to use : then you either need to encode the colon (perhaps to `%3A`) or you need to inject that value as part of (or after) the parameter injection (which will probably require you to subclass the paginator).

Comment: To encode the colon with %3A will not wotk in Restkit 0.26. Even to escape the colon with a '//: ' as mentioned in SocKit does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the URL have this scheme:

> ..elements/DOCCOMPANY_FILE:1502328/structure

That means in my case: "From element with key "DOCCompany:150.." GET its structure. 
This will not work with the RKPaginator Class in restkit.

But if you can edit your local sources, add this to the RKPaginator or subclass it:

```
-(id)valueForUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key {
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@":%@",key];
}
```

This will ignore all unknown parameters in URL in the pagination class and works well for me.